# How to update a record in a database with an HTML form using php and mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have HTML with a textbox and a select box. I want the user to pick a flat number from the drop down select box which picks up the number from my database. I then want the user then to enter a new monthly rent in the textbox. Once the user clicks the submit button, I want it to update the database monthly rent depending on what flat number has been picked. I can get the flat number picked up from the database, but can't seem to get the information from the textbox and change it in the database.

Here is my code

Changeback.php (back end)

```html
<?php
include "connect.php";
if(isset($_POST['MonthlyRent'])){
$MonthlyRent = $_POST['MonthlyRent'];
$FlatCode = $_POST['FlatCode'];

$query = "UPDATE MonthlyRent set MonthlyRent = ($MonthlyRent) where FlatCode = ($FlatCode) ";

mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("Invalid query");
$numrows = mysqli_affected_rows($con);
echo "number of affected rows is " . $numrows;
exit( print_r( $_POST ) );
mysqli_close($con);

}
?>
```

change.php (front end)

```html
<html><head><title>Connect to Database</title></head><body> 

<font size="4"> Enter owner details</font><br><br> 
<form action="changeback.php" method="post" >


Monthly Rent <input  type="text" name="MonthlyRent">
Flat Code <select name="FlatCode">

<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die ("No connection"); 
mysqli_select_db($con , "flat") or die ("db will not open"); 

$query = "SELECT distinct FlatCode from FLAT"; 

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Invalid query");  
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
      echo "<option value=\"" . $rows[0] . "\">" . $rows[0] . "</option>"; 
}

echo "</select>"; 
 mysqli_close($con);


 ?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Value"> 
</form></body></html>
```

Comment: Is FlatCode a number or a string?

Comment: it would be a number and a string its set in the database as varchar

Comment: Try FlatCode = '$FlatCode' in the UPDATE.

Comment: still no luck, it now says invalid query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your UPDATE statement, where you (1) have placed the `MonthlyRent` column name where the `FLAT` table name should have been, and (2) have not put quotes around the flat code value.

Change:

```
$query = "UPDATE MonthlyRent set MonthlyRent = ($MonthlyRent) where FlatCode = ($FlatCode) ";
```

To:

```
// Always escape user input to reduce risk of errors and security holes
$escapedMonthlyRent = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $MonthlyRent);
$escapedFlatCode    = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $FlatCode);

$query = "update FLAT set MonthlyRent = '$escapedMonthlyRent' "
    ."where FlatCode = '$escapedFlatCode'";
```

Comment: I am now getting this message when trying to add my information. "number of affected rows is 0Array ( [MonthlyRent] => 344 [FlatCode] => w3k48 ) 1"

Comment: Good to hear! Please mark my answer as the correct one if it helped solve your problem, and good luck on your project :)